# Windows-Tags in .m4a metadata

Tags: windows-10, metadata, m4a

In Windows 10 it is possible to add tags to a number of file types, including .m4a files. What I mean are these:
[image: Windows Tags]

I would like to read those tags programatically, but I have found nothing that tells me which field windows uses for these tags. The only hint I could gather is that for .wmv files, it uses the category field of the metadata.

I have also tried reading the complete metadata of an example file with ffmpeg but it didn't output the tags I set.

So where are these tags saved?

Answer (score 1):

Those tags are held in the `Microsoft:Category` tag. There are almost no programs out there that will write to this field.

The paid program, [MP4 Video & Audio Tag Editor](https://www.3delite.hu/Object%20Pascal%20Developer%20Resources/MP4VideoAndAudioTagEditor.html) can write this tag and as of version 12.21, [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) can also write this tag.

Comment: Aren't the atom names limited to 4 characters?

Comment: I went through it with the debugger and found it in an atom called "Xtra" with some proprietary format, but with some fiddling it's parse-able...

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  I tend to use the names Exiftool uses.  You can see more at [exiftool's Xtra tags list](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Microsoft.html#Xtra).